# how to rewrite url using RouteConfig.cs file in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need your help because i searched but my problem is not solved. Thanks so much.

I have url: `http://example.com/products/?sec=2` (2 is id of sectionname)
And now, i want to show http://example.com/products/sectionname`

Please let me know how i can do in RouteConfig.cs file? (i'm new in mvc4 and c#, so i can't understand what i see in google search).
Below is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int cat=-1, int sec=-1, fea=-1)
{
   var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.Publish).OrderByDescending(p=>p.ProductDate).ToList();
   if (sec!=-1)
  {
    products = products.Where(p => p.Category.SectionId ==sec).ToList();      
  }
  if (cat!=-1)
  {
    products = products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == cat).ToList();
  }
  if (fea!=-1)
  {
   products = products.Where(p => p.Feature == true).ToList();
  }
   return View(products);
}
```

And my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "section name", // Route name
                "Products/section/{sec}", // URL with parameters
                new
                {
                    controller = "Products",
                    action = "Index", sec =UrlParameter.Optional,
                }
            );
```

and when i run my project, it is still http://example.com/products/?sec=2

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve from your question. I suggest you read about MVC routing and show us your route setup and what URL you intended to handle. One link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

in my view, i changed from `<a href="/Products/?sec=@item.Id">@item.SectionName</a>` to `<a href="/Products/Sect/@item.Id">@item.SectionName</a>`

It work.